# How can Convert Str without range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code is good to convert str within range, for example the following code converts to float or int within range of 5. I want to convert the existing data of the whole column to int or float. How I can do that? I need help?

```
df= pd.DataFrame(range(5), columns=['a'])
df.a = df.a.astype(float)
```

When I code like this, it gives me an error:

```
df= pd.DataFrame, columns=['a'])
df.a = df.a.astype(float)
```

Comment: `df= pd.DataFrame, columns=['a'])` looks like invalid syntax.

Comment: Plase provide some sample data. What's your input? What's the desired output?

Comment: experience  test_score  oral_score    salary
0           5           8           9  thousand
1           6           8           6     45000
2           5           6           7     60000
3           2          10          10     65000
4           7           9           6     70000

Comment: I want convert salary(column) to int.

Comment: What was wrong with `df.a = df.a.astype(int)`?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error ? This syntaxe should work

```
import numpy as np
df.a = df.a.astype(np.float32)
```

If your data is originally of type string, your error might be related to space characters. Try do do this first:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, the issue is with `df= pd.DataFrame, columns=['a'])`

You need to provide data to transform into a dataframe. Below is an example that would work, by feeding a list to a dataframe. Note that the result prints out as "numpy.float64" when run.

```
import pandas as pd

salary = {'a':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)

df.a = df.a.astype(float)

print(type(df.a[0]))
```